# Magento 2 : Change default REST API response

Tags: magento2, module, orders, api, rest-api

I have an order collection get out via API
[image]

How can I change some value in API response via custom module
[image]

Comment: Instead of changing existing attribute value , use extension_attribute for send additional data.

Comment: I already know how to send more data, my problem is how to change the existing attribute value.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want change product_option.extension_attributes.custom_options.option_value ?

Comment: exactly, do you have any idea?

Comment: @MichaelHa Are you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this *product_option.extension_attributes.custom_options.option_value* it's a value that added via extension attributes.

In Magento 2 extension attributes are not magically saved to the database or populated, so based on this value above have to be added via ***plugin, observer or even rewrite***.

The idea is to locate this logic which is responsible for filling that extension attribute and change as you want.

For example, if this is a ***plugin*** you can disable it via *di*, and create your own plugin which modifies the data.

Comment: Thank for the answer, Where does this value come from. how to find exactly.

Comment: To help you with that, I need more information. Please update your answer: 1. Which REST endpoint you use? 2. Do you have any modules installed which are related to REST? 3. Which version of Magento you have?